# In the context of “encapsulation”, what is meant by the phrase “protecting objects from unwanted accesses by a client”

Tags: c, encapsulation

In Chapter 19 of “*C Programming: A Modern Approach*”, the idea of encapsulation (although ‘meager’ in C programming language) is introduced.

As motivation for implementation of encapsulation, the author alludes to the importance of protecting objects from being accessed by clients. Comments about avoiding the “corruption” of data fields within structures are referenced.

Perhaps because I am still quite a novice in software development in general (I’ve only ever written small programs...with a few .h and .c files), I don’t really understand the necessity of “protecting objects”.

Ultimately, doesn’t the programmer (with explicit code) dictate whether or not an object is directly accessed? It’s not like the compiler will “accidentally” access a structure and modify members, right?

From my understanding, the “corrupting access” would only occur if there was an explicit piece of code that said “access that structure and alter the data”...and presumably the piece of code responsible for initiating that action was user-generated.

Thus, is the only purpose of encapsulation to protect the “purpose of program” from user-errors incurred throughout the actual programming process?

Thanks!

Comment: Components should be accessed via well defined public APIs with internal state protected from direct client code access. Example: A component may have x/y coordinates. Instead of allowing client code direct access to change the coords there would only be well defined APIs to moveLeft, moveRight, etc. With the APIs, the component can stop the coords moving off a predefined grid in contrast to direct client access which may leave the component with invalid cooord values.

Comment: @kaylum I appreciate the response, but you’re using a lexicon that I simply have no base level familiarity with. My programming experience is literally limited to the 19 chapters of this book.

Comment: Well, in simpler terms, encapsulation is the idea that chunks of code should "own" their own data. If chunk A "owns" its data, it controls what other chunks can do with that data -- read it, perhaps, or change it; or nothing at all. We need to do this to make the problem of managing data in a large program a reasonably tractable one. I use the word "chunk" because the features available to enforce encapsulation differ from one language to another.

Comment: You say "It’s not like the compiler will “accidentally” access a structure..." But it's not the compiler we have to worry about -- it's people, with their limited memories and intellectual powers. The problems resulting from lack of encapsulation grow rapidly along with the program.

Comment: @KevinBoone ahhh. So it fundamentally IS a prophylactic measure against user error...at least it would seem.

Comment: @S.Cramer -- well, I don't think it's quite correct to use the term "error" to describe the human inability to manage thousands of individual data items across thousands of lines of code. Without some strategy for managing the use of this data, writing a program of any complexity would be an insurmountable intellectual challenge. For example, it's possible (albeit not for me) to play ten games of chess simultaneously. But would it be possible to play chess on a board with 80x80 squares and a couple hundred different pieces? Programming is like that -- we need strategies to manage  complexity.

Comment: @KevinBoone so it is not about hacking? it is about protecting data from limited memory of developers that work on that large project to not access the data accidentaly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my understanding, the “corrupting access” would only occur if there was an explicit piece of code that said “access that structure and alter the data”...and presumably the piece of code responsible for initiating that action was user-generated.

Yes, and that is exactly the problem. If users *can* access internal structs / objects / whatever, there is a non-zero chance that they will. If you know some internal object is not useful for end-users, why not prevent them from accessing it? That way you can guarantee that your library works as intended, because its internal structure or objects were only modified by code that you wrote yourself.

> Perhaps because I am still quite a novice in software development in general (I’ve only ever written small programs...with a few .h and .c files), I don’t really understand the necessity of “protecting objects”.
>
> Ultimately, doesn’t the programmer (with explicit code) dictate whether or not an object is directly accessed? It’s not like the compiler will “accidentally” access a structure and modify members, right?

If you didn't restrict access to internals, you are placing the responsibility of keeping the internal objects correct on the end user. For large libraries, this can be quite difficult to manage. Again, restricting access to things a user doesn't need to access is a way to absolve them of responsibilty and to prevent errors.